# Escaping double quotes in JSON array using Json.NET

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm using Json.NET to generate some JSON that I write into a webrequest stream.  Here's the code I'm using:

```
dynamic jsonObject = new JObject();
jsonObject.keyName1 = "XXX";
jsonObject.keyName2 = 180539;
jsonObject.keyName3 = new JArray() as dynamic;

dynamic jsonObject2 = new JObject();
jsonObject2.what = "xxxxx";
jsonObject.keyName3.Add(jsonObject2);

jsonObject2 = new JObject();
jsonObject2.what = "yyyyy";
jsonObject2.duration = 30;
jsonObject.keyName3.Add(jsonObject2);

jsonObject2 = new JObject();
jsonObject2.what = "zzzz";
jsonObject2.keyName3.Add(jsonObject2);

jsonObject.keyName4 = "123";

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObject);
```

This code produces the following JSON:

```
{
  "keyName1": "XXX",
  "keyName2": 180539,
  "keyName3": [
    {"what": "xxxxx"},
    {"what": "yyyyy", "duration":30},
    {"what": "zzzzz"}],
  "keyName4":"123"
}
```

Unfortunately, the web service that processes this JSON expects the keys and values inside of an array as well as the array itself to be escaped like this:

```
{
  "keyName1": "XXX",
  "keyName2": 180539,
  "keyName3": "[
    {\"what\":\"xxxxx\"},
    {\"what\":\"yyyyy\",\"duration\":30},
    {\"what\":\"zzzzz\"}]",
  "keyName4":"123"
}
```

Is it possible to do this with Json.NET?

Comment: Looks like you should serialize the `keyName3` (license) array to JSON separately. They seem to be expecting that the array is a JSON string, not JSON objects.

Comment: Thanks, Ron.  Your suggestion to serialize the array separately was right on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

...

dynamic jsonObject = new JObject();
jsonObject.keyName1 = "XXX";
jsonObject.keyName2 = 180539;
jsonObject.keyName3 = new JArray() as dynamic;

dynamic jsonArrayObject = new JArray() as dynamic;

dynamic jsonObject2 = new JObject();
jsonObject2.what = "xxxxx";
jsonArrayObject.Add(jsonObject2);

jsonObject2 = new JObject();
jsonObject2.what = "yyyyy";
jsonObject2.duration = 30;
jsonArrayObject.Add(jsonObject2);

jsonObject2 = new JObject();
jsonObject2.what = "zzzz";
jsonArrayObject.Add(jsonObject2);

var jsonArrayString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonArrayObject, Formatting.None);

jsonObject.keyName3 = jsonArrayString;
jsonObject.keyName4 = "123";

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObject, Formatting.None);
```

Comment: You're right!  Serializing the array separately did the trick.  Thanks very much!

Answer (score -2):

In .Net4+  `System.Web.HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode`

Comment: You're probably going to need to add more explanation to your answer.  As it stands, this answer is flagged as very low quality and may end up getting deleted.